# SQL Query can't find mistake

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
DECLARE @i int = 0
WHILE @i < 100 BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
    INSERT INTO lottery (ticket, bought) VALUES (@i, false)
END
```

MySQL server

> Error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @i int = 0 WHILE @i < 100 BEGIN
>   SET @i = @i + 1     INSERT INTO lott' at line 1

But It says an error is in it but not where.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the first line like this:

```
DECLARE @i int DEFAULT 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're creating a stored procedure.

If you have multiple statements in a stored procedure you need to seperate them with a semicolumn, which is the standard delimiter so you'll have to change this at forehand. I.e:

```
DELIMTER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE procedurename ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    SET i := 0;
    WHILE i < 100
    BEGIN
        SET i := i + 1;
        INSERT INTO lottery (ticket, bought) VALUES (i, 0);
    END;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Note that user variables are connection based, and variables declared in the procedure are only in the scope of the procedure itself.